# How to perform outer subtraction along an axis in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I used to perform an outer subtraction on two one-dimensional arrays as follows to receive a single two-dimensional arrays that contains all pairs of subtractions:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5)
b = np.arange(3)
result = np.subtract.outer(a, b)
assert result.shape == (5, 3)
assert np.all(result == np.array([[aa - bb for bb in b] for aa in a ])) # no rounding errors
```

Now the state space switches to two dimensions, and I would like to perform the same operation, but only perform each subtraction on the two values on the last axis of the arrays A and B:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(5 * 2).reshape(-1, 2)
B = np.arange(3 * 2).reshape(-1, 2)
result = np.subtract.outer(A, B)

# Obviously the following does not hold, because here we have got all subtractions, therefore the shape (5, 2, 3, 2)
# I would like to exchange np.subtract.outer such that the following holds:
# assert result.shape == (5, 3, 2)

expected_result = np.array([[aa - bb for bb in B] for aa in A ])
assert expected_result.shape == (5, 3, 2)

# That's what I want to hold:
# assert np.all(result == expected_result) # no rounding errors
```

Is there a "numpy-only" solution to perform this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expand/reshape `A` to (5, 1, 2) and `B` to (1, 3, 2) and let the broadcasting do the job:

```
A[:, None, :] - B[None, :, :]
```

Answer (score 1):

`A[:, None] - B[None, :]` does it.

```py
A = np.arange(5 * 2).reshape(-1, 2)
B = np.arange(3 * 2).reshape(-1, 2)

expected_result = np.array([[aa - bb for bb in B] for aa in A ])

C = A[:, None] - B[None, :]

np.allclose(expected_result, C)
#> True
```

The exact same syntax works for your first example too. This is because with your requirement, you are combining every first axis element of `A` with every first axis element of `B`.